# Is the EE:SE infrastructure not properly monitored?

Tags: support

We just now had a *very minor* outage, probably below 2 minutes.

EE:SE showed this screen:

[image]

When I followed the link, the monitoring system didn't detect any issue:

[image]

I switched back and forth, just to make sure that the issue wasn't resolved in that instance.

---

The reason I bring this up isn't because it's a big deal. But maybe someone from the IT department could check if the monitoring system for EE:SE is configured correctly.

Comment: I agree; it provides no help at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the monitoring only works for the main site and not the subsites. My guess is it could have been some site maintenance that they had to do or a problem with the local caching servers